# Visual Studio 2017(vb.net)のwebBrowserでopenLayer(v5.3.0)にて国土地理院地図がスクリプトエラーとなる

Tags: vb.net

VB.NETのwebBrowserコントロールでOpenLayerにて国土地理院の地図を表示しようとするとスクリプトエラーが出てしまいます。スクリプトエラー画面２枚とデバック時のエラー画面１枚をキャプチャーしましたのでご教示頂けないでしょうか？一応html形式では表示できたことは確認しました。よろしくお願いします。

[image: スクリプトエラー画面、デバック時のエラー画面]

Answer (score 1):

WebBrowserコントロールは互換性のために[既定ではIE7モードで動作](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)#browser-emulation)します（更にIE7モードはコンテンツに応じてIE5モードまで落とすことができます）。

WebBrowserコートロールをロードする前に次のレジストリを設定しておくことで動作モードを変更することができます。

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (or HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
   SOFTWARE
      Microsoft
         Internet Explorer
            Main
               FeatureControl
                  FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
                     contoso.exe = (DWORD) 00009000
```

`contoso.exe`の部分は実行ファイル名、`00009000`の部分は動作させたいIEバージョンを指定します。例えばIE11モードで動作させたいのであれば10進数で`11000`など。

Comment: sayuri様ご教示ありがとうございました。１つ進んでスクリプトエラー画面は表示されなくなりWebページエラー画面から表示されるようになりました。

Comment: sayuri様 ご教示頂きました内容で動作しました。当方がレジストリに登録の際にQWORDで追加してしまっていました。どうもすみませんでした。

Comment: @らいよん 解決したようでしたら、[回答を承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)していただけますでしょうか。